# Regex to check if a single quote is preceeded by another single quote

Tags: java, regex

I would like to write a regex to validate if a single quote is preceeded by another single quote.

Valid strings:

```
azerty''uiop
aze''rty''uiop
''azertyuiop
azerty''uiop''
azerty ''uiop''
azerty''''uiop
azerty''''uiop''''
```

Invalid strings:

```
azerty'uiop
aze'rty'uiop
'azertyuiop
azerty'uiop'
azerty 'uiop'
azerty'''uiop
```

Comment: Are you wanting the whole line? If so this should work `/^.*'{2}.*$/g`

Comment: That would give a successful match on the final negative case.

Comment: Why is `azerty''''uiop` legal, but not `azerty'''uiop`?

Comment: Because I only want an even number of following single quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done in one line:

```
inputString.matches("(?:[^']|'')*+");
```

The regex simply means, the string can contain 0 or more of

- Non-quote character `[^']`
  OR
- A pair of consecutive quotes `''`

I used possessive version (`*+`) of 0 or more quantifier (`*`). Since it would be lengthy to explain what *possessive quantifier* means, I will refer you to [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) to learn about it. Simply put, it is an optimization.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regex, just use `.replace()` to replace all sequences of two single quotes by nothing, then test whether you *still* find a single quote; if yes, the string is invalid:

```
if (input.replace("''", "").indexOf('\'') != -1)
    // Not valid!
```

If you also want to consider that strings with no single quotes are valid, you'll have to create a temporary variable:

```
public boolean isValid(final String input)
{
    final String s = input.replace("''", "");
    return s.equals(input) ? true : s.indexOf('\'') == -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a very fast solution? Try the next:

```
public static boolean isValid(String str) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char c = chars[i];
        if (c == '\'') {
            found++;
        } else {
            if (found > 0 && found % 2 != 0) {
                return false;
            }
            found = 0;
        }
    }
    if (found > 0 && found % 2 != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you only need to use a boolean to do this: set it to `true` at first, toggle it `found = !found` when encounter `'`, and check whether it is `false` in `else` branch.

Comment: Could be, but that means more bytecode instructions. The last `if` it's for `'` in the last position.

Comment: (I am aware about the last if, I was talking about the if statement inside loop). bytecode instruction doesn't equate to the number of machine instructions generated. I expect not much of an improvement in performance, but I will refrain from arguing, since I it will require setting up for micro-benchmarking. However, I am quite sure that regardless of the small details, the looping implementation is faster than regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code bellow too:

```
str.matches("([^\']*(\'){2}[^\']*)+");
```

I think `"([^\']*(\'){2}[^\']*)+"` is easy to grasp, for the beginners. But this is not the best way to do this. It dies (runs into backtracking hell) when running for long input.

Comment: Your expression dies (runs into backtracking hell) on a slightly long invalid input: http://www.regex101.com/r/jN3iQ1 (the extra addition is necessary to run on the tester - the function is equivalent, though).

Comment: Yup, that was inevitable... :P

Comment: No, it is not. My regex can run on long string very efficiently (at the same complexity as a non-regex solution, but is slightly slower due to regex engine overhead).

Comment: Lolz, I was not talking about your regex, I was talking about mine.